# Dateadd in SQLServer constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have this constraint

```
([dateOfBirth]>dateadd(year,(-21),getdate()))
```

When I try to insert this statement this constraint is not letting me to.

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]
VALUES ('F1324','132456789','James','1989-09-24','Orchard Park, Tagore Lane');
```

What is it that I am making mistake here?

Comment: shouldn't it be `<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint is not letting you insert that record because the current date minus 21 years (which would be `1993-10-11` at this time) does not satisfy the condition:

`1989-09-24 > 1993-10-11`

Assuming you mean to only allow people 21 years and older, switch the constraint to

```
([dateOfBirth]<dateadd(year,(-21),getdate()))
```